# I have $20k of imaginary gains from trading last year due to wash sale rules. Should/can I take mark to market?

Tags: united-states, taxes, trading, investing

I have traded for most of the year while I work at my full time job as a software developer. I am using it to augment my income. I like working in academia but it just doesn't pay that well! I started in late January and made trades in every month of the year. The median holding time per position was about 3 days (so I was trying to capitalize on short time price swings).

I'm new at trading, so I made some emotional mistakes and if my calculations are right <strike>I lost about $5000</strike> I gained about $1400 by the end of 2013. I calculated this by doing the mark to market on 12/31 and subtracting the account balance <strike>(~69,200)</strike> (~75,900) as of that day from the total amount of cash I've put in (~74,500) as of that day. The numbers above are corrected; I had forgotten to mark my SPY position to market. So my actual gain was ~$1400, but according to my Scottrade tax report, due to the wash sale rules, it looks like I gained $20k! This is punitive.

The only way out that I can see is the mark to market election, but I'm wary of it. I'm not certain I qualify, and I'm not certain I want to KEEP trading every year from now on (I might want to transition to a more traditional investing pattern if there is a big correction in the market). But I am certain I don't want to pay a few thousand dollars of tax on some imaginary gains! :( Does anybody know specifics about how hard it is to get permission from the IRS to come back from the M2M election? And are there any red flags in this scenario which would mean I'm not even eligible for it?

```
Category                Gross Proceeds Cost Basis     Wash Sale Loss Disallowed  Net Gain/Loss
A (basis reported)      $1,698,367.79  $1,854,734.46  $168,059.55                $11,692.88   
B (basis not reported)  $3,104,256.07  $3,534,153.57  $438,278.99                $8,381.49    
Total                   $4,802,623.86  $5,388,888.03  $606,338.54                $20,074.37
```

Comment: Punitive? I hope you weren't blindsided by the wash rules. It's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Hi Matt. Could you please add a country tag? It's required when taxes are the subject. Thank you.

Comment: Do other countries have wash sale rules?

Comment: Wash sale gains?  I'm not certain I follow.  IRC § 1091 is only about disallowed losses.  Are you saying that the disallowed losses are $15k, such that your tax gain is $20k while your economic gain was only $5k?  Note that for disallowed wash sale losses you will still get those losses later in your basis when you fully exit the position.  They are deferred but not erased.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer We do have a similar rule in Canada but it is more commonly referred to as the superficial loss rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you did not elect mark to market by April 15, 2013, then **you cannot claim mark to market for tax year 2013**.  You were not timely, so the issue is moot for the tax year at issue.  See [Pub 550](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p550.pdf) (p 70) or [Topic 429](http://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc429.html).  Sorry to bear bad news.

Note that your **wash sale losses are only suspended** until you exit the stock, so this is not a straight loss.  See [IRC § 1091(d)](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/1091#d).  They should be included in your basis of the over-traded stock.  This is a time value issue, so you lost the value of those losses for 2013 but they still exist, suspended in basis, for 2014 and beyond.

It will preserve your flexibility to avoid mark to market and be a regular investor.  You can time your income.  The most commonly cited reason to avoid mark to market is of course the **phantom income problem** - you must sell an investment to find the cash to pay the tax on that investment.  That may make sense if you are liquid and seldom hold stocks or investments for long periods.  But phantom income is not a fun problem to have and you may find it less convenient than dodging wash sale rules.

Comment: Yes, I did notice the "timely election" bit in littleadv's link. It's amazing to me that in all my googling about mark to market, that page didn't show up. I was getting 10-15 year old pages which didn't say anything about having to elect for it before the fact (which I assume, back then, was not necessary). I also read there that m2m traders can have normal investments as long as they keep records of which stocks are normal investments (the suggested approach is a separate brokerage account). Wouldn't that avoid the phantom income problem?

Comment: I usually add "irs.gov" when doing a google search on taxes.  There's also a complete listing of all the official IRS Publications here: http://www.irs.gov/publications/index.html?RefNo=635206387959453234.  There are also multiple places to look at the internal revenue code for free, but apparently most people don't enjoy reading through the tax code.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand 1091(d). Is it saying that for my FB trading, which I haven't had a position in for a while, and resulted in a net loss of ~17000 (ouch!), the wash sale losses should no longer count? I'm not sure what "time value" issue means.

Comment: I'm not sure about electing mark to market for only some activities and not others.  I mostly know taxation of derivatives from the corporate perspective, not the traders.  I'll poke around and see if I notice something.  Pub 550 would be the place to look.

Comment: The 1040 schedule D instructions under the `Mark-To-Market Election for
Traders` section seem fairly clear: `If you hold securities for investment, you must identify them as such in your records on the day you acquired them (for example, by holding the securities in a separate brokerage account). Securities held for investment are not
marked-to-market.`

Comment: §1091(a) disallows losses from a wash sale, which occurs if a purchase happens within +30 or -30 days of a sale of the same stock.  §1091(d) puts the disallowed loss into the basis of that stock.  So you still get the tax benefit, but only when you fully the exit the stock.  This prevents you from electively recognizing losses by overlapping purchases and sales of the same stock.  The time value problem is that a dollar of tax benefit in 2014 is more valuable than a dollar of tax benefit in 2015.  http://www.investopedia.com/terms/t/timevalueofmoney.asp

Comment: Oh, that's a name I didn't know for something I knew intuitively. :) My last FB trade in 2013 was 11/19 and it was a "full" exit I guess since I sold all my shares of it. So should I be able to recognize those losses in 2013?

Comment: Yeah, sounds like you can elect out of §475(f) mark-to-market with §475(f)(1)(B) declaration on the day of purchase.  So if you declare it investment on the day you buy it (and I'm sure there's a process for that), then you can get out of mark-to-market.  But it doesn't get you out of phantom income.  If you hold lots of stocks as M2M, then you may have to sell them to pay the tax on those investments.  An archetypal M2M trader will not have long-term investments, because that's the whole point.  But theoretically phantom income can still happen and you have to plan for that.

Comment: It's hard to comment directly on your tax burdens because tax plus portfolio can be complicated.  In general, if someone gets a wash sale disallowed loss, they can recognize the loss when they sell that stock.  If they hold any options, contracts, or derivatives of the stock, that could continue to block the loss.

Comment: Yes I understand the phantom income problem of M2M, but if at some point I decide to stop trading, I just have to start exclusively using my investment account. It seems the M2M is really the MOST flexible as it lets you have both worlds. I've never held any options/contracts/derivatives of FB, so you think the Scottrade 1099 is wrong about disallowing all these losses?

Comment: It's flexible if you don't mind designating all your investment purchases on day one.  There may be problems if the investment security is similar to M2M securities and you should probably have a separate account, maybe with a separate broker (Proposed Reg §1.475(f)-2).  It can be a hassle if you engage in frequent purchases.  Re 1099, did they provide basis?  If you are confident that you exited a position, then § 1091(d) says you can count the disallowed wash sale loss in your basis.  So you can decide your tax position.  You might contact your broker with this issue of basis.

Comment: I added a table from Scottrade showing what it says my Gross Proceeds, Cost Basis, Wash Sale Loss Disallowed, and Net Gain/Loss were. I'm quite baffled by it to be honest. How can my cost basis be so much higher than my gross proceeds and yet I didn't lose that much money? After further investigation, it seems that Scottrade is properly reporting my FB loss. I think it's the cumulative disallowed wash losses from other stocks that I WAS still active in during December that are causing the gain. I haven't pinned it down yet exactly though. It looks like there's no way out of this gain though.

Comment: Did you have closely grouped purchases and sales of any other stocks?  I don't see where you got $5k as your end of 2013 position.  You have 600k in wash sale disallowed losses.  If you had exited all stocks, for illustration, then disallowed wash sale losses would all be usable in basis.  I think you may need to investigate the source of all these disallowed losses.  Either: 1) you have wash sales in other stocks, 2) Scottrade did not adequately track basis, or 3) you have made an error in estimating your end-13 position as $5k gain.

Comment: It seems possible that their system correctly tracked disallowed losses but forgot to add them back in to basis on final disposition.  This may require discussion with Scottrade or a financial professional.

Comment: @NL7 just pointing out - you clearly know your stuff, but at some point you should let go the free counseling and turn the OP to a licensed professional. It sounds like you're a tax accountant, so I'm sure you know the liability issues you can create for yourself with such deeply individual counseling, even if it is for free and anonymous...

Comment: After much wrangling with Excel, I found I forgot to mark SPY to market in my original post so there is actually a small gain for the year. My daily Scottrade balance for 12/31 matches my Excel math within $100. I just have no idea how to properly calculate which of the wash sales are actually supposed to count against me. For the stocks I had positions in within 30 days of 12/31, I had ~$497k of wash sales according to the Scottrade ledger. I think you're right @littleadv, I need to consult someone professionally. I just don't know who. Thank you both for the helpful information!

Answer (score 4):

[Here are the details](http://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc429.html). Whether it is *hard* to get the permission to revoke the election is hard to tell, since no-one can tell the future. Form 3115 is filed routinely by tax professionals to request changes in accounting methods. It may trigger an audit if you only use it for one year and have substantial losses that would not otherwise be allowed. If you qualify for the trader terms - then you just show it during the audit.

I would suggest getting a professional help you here. The main pitfall I see is the requirement for the activity to be **substantial**. $5K profit and $70K overall balance doesn't strike *me* as substantial for a software engineer (i.e.: I expect your overall income is significantly more than those $5K). But I'm not a tax professional and definitely not an IRS revenue agent, so what the heck do I know...

Comment: I've thought about professional help, but I'm worried about how much qualified help would cost. I'm worried that run of the mill tax advisers wouldn't really know about mark to market. And this would be the first year I've needed anything more than 1040EZ, so the first time I've needed professional help.

Comment: @Matt you got more than enough here for free from NL7 and myself, but in the end - you get what you paid for. If the matter is complicated and a lot of money is at stake - being cheap may turn out **very** costly.